# Merge two files in C, any files

Tags: c, linux, file, io, merge

I am trying t find a program that can merge two files, any files like .nc files

I need to duplicate a .nc file that is 1.5GB long and I don't feel like opening it up as a text and copy and pasting its contents so that I can make it bigger

I found this code online, but it doesn't work for large files like mine?

It works for simple text files that are small I noticed

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char f1[10],f2[10];
    puts("enter the name of file 1");      /*getting the names of file to be concatenated*/
    scanf("%s",f1);
    puts("enter the name of file 2");
    scanf("%s",f2);
    FILE *fa,*fb,*fc;
    fa=fopen(f1,"r");             /*opening the files in read only mode*/
    fb=fopen(f2,"r");
    fc=fopen("merge.txt","w+");   /*opening a new file in write,update mode*/
    char str1[200];
    char ch1,ch2;
    int n=0,w=0;
    while( (( ch1=fgetc(fa) )!=EOF)&&((ch2=fgetc(fb))!=EOF))
    {
        if(ch1!=EOF)             /*getting lines in alternately from two files*/
        { 
            ungetc(ch1,fa);
            fgets(str1,199,fa);
            fputs(str1,fc);
            if(str1[0]!='\n') n++;      /*counting no. of lines*/
        }
        if(ch2!=EOF)
        { 
            ungetc(ch2,fb);
            fgets(str1,199,fb);
            fputs(str1,fc);
            if(str1[0]!='\n')n++;        /*counting no.of lines*/
        }
    }
    rewind(fc);
    while((ch1=fgetc(fc))!=EOF)       /*countig no.of words*/
    {
        ungetc(ch1,fc);
        fscanf(fc,"%s",str1);
        if(str1[0]!=' '||str1[0]!='\n')
            w++;
    }
    fprintf(fc,"\n\n number of lines = %d \n number of words is = %d\n",n,w-1);
    /*appendig comments in the concatenated file*/
    fclose(fa);
    fclose(fb);
    fclose(fc);
}
```

I am merging the same file, so that it duplicating it, but when it spits out the outcome of the file, it says the file is only 8,668 bytes?!? How is this possible when the original file is 1.5GB?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: So what do you want to do exactly? Please give an example input of two files with about 5 lines each and what you expect as output.

Comment: Suppose this is the data that is being read in the .nc file for 1.5GB long

Comment: '4344 4601 0000 0000 0000 000a 0000 0004
0000 0003 6c6f 6e00 0000 0090 0000 0003
6c61 7400 0000 0049 0000 0004 7469 6d65
0000 05b4 0000 0005 6e62 6e64 7300 0000
0000 0002 0000 000c 0000 0007 0000 000b'

Comment: I would like to merge the two same files so that I can basically double the file size

Comment: The code shown works by alternately merging lines of text, and has a line buffer size of 200 chars. You mention only one file and not its format, but unless you have two _text_ files as input and neither of them has lines longer than 199 characters (including newline), it's not going to work.

Comment: If your data isn't text, you cannot expect `fgets` and `fputs` to be useful.  Your data clearly has null bytes in it.  (ie, it's not text)

Comment: Do you just want to produce a big file, or is it important to have lines in output alternating? Perhaps a simple `cat file1 file2 > newfile` would be enough?

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes you are correct, it does not have text, it is in a different format, any ideas on a program that can do this for me tho?

Comment: @Axel yes thats the way the file is viewed in text from the .nc file, I just want to double the size of the file so that I can run some more test's on that specific file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write a program to do this, one already exists.

```
cat foo.nc bar.nc > foobar.nc
```

`bar.nc` will be concatenated onto the end of `foo.nc` in `foobar.nc`. This works with binary and textual data.  If you want to add to an existing file:

```
cat foo.nc >> bar.nc
```

`foo.nc` will be added to the end of `bar.nc`.

See `man cat` for more information.

Comment: +1: In Windows, for text files, you can open a Command Prompt and use `type` instead of `cat`.

Comment: oh perfect! Thank you! Does that mean I can something like this? 'file.nc file.nc > newfile.nc'?

Comment: Yes, but the (linux) command name is `cat`, so you need `cat file.nc file.nc > newfile.nc`.